# Rank decomposition of matrices over $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-analysis

Given an integer matrix $M\in\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ of real rank $k$ what is the minimum and maximum number of rank $1$ matrices $B_1$ to $B_t$ we require so that $M\equiv\sum_{i=1}^tB_i\bmod 2$?

1. If $\mathbb F_2$ rank of $M$ is $k'$ then we need $t=k'$. I am asking the best gap between $k$ and $k'$.
2. If $k=n$ when is $k'<n$?
   I guess the converse $k<n$ and $k'=n$ does not happen.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_2$ rank can be smaller than the real rank, for example, when all entries of $M$ are even.

Comment: Also, if $k'=n$, then $\det(M)\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, so $k=n$ as well.